# Stricter lint of Golang in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, lint

I'm using VSCode for my Golang projects with the default lint settings, and I can't find a way to have a strict lint of my Go files, underlining the problems in the code, that would allow me to abide strictly to official Go guidelines, such as:

- Starting comments of functions with the function name,
- Using only camel case in variables,
- Using only snake case in package name,
- etc...

How to get strict linting behaviour in VSCode?

Comment: _You can add additional lint checks using the go.lintOnSave setting and configuring your choice of linting tool (staticcheck, golangci-lint, or revive) using the go.lintTool setting._ - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go#_build-test-and-diagnose

Comment: Moreover, golangci-lint has a comprehensive set of configuration options. https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/

Comment: There is no way for us to tell how your coworker as configured Goland, or how to tell you to match that configuration. The VSCode Go extension can be configured to use any linter, with any configuration.

Comment: Indeed I ended up using golangci-lint with a mix of revive and staticcheck as well as some other specific linters like bodyclose. This does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  [staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io) is VSCode's [default go linter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go#_build-test-and-diagnose).

Staticcheck's [default configuration](https://staticcheck.io/docs/configuration#example-configuration) ignores certain rules.  You can opt back in to all rules with your own `staticcheck.conf` with a `checks=["all"]` entry.

```sh
# https://staticcheck.io/docs/configuration

# checks = ["all", "-ST1000", "-ST1003", "-ST1016", "-ST1020", "-ST1021", "-ST1022", "-ST1023"]
checks = ["all"]
initialisms = ["ACL", "API", "ASCII", "CPU", "CSS", "DNS",
    "EOF", "GUID", "HTML", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "ID",
    "IP", "JSON", "QPS", "RAM", "RPC", "SLA",
    "SMTP", "SQL", "SSH", "TCP", "TLS", "TTL",
    "UDP", "UI", "GID", "UID", "UUID", "URI",
    "URL", "UTF8", "VM", "XML", "XMPP", "XSRF",
    "XSS", "SIP", "RTP", "AMQP", "DB", "TS"]
dot_import_whitelist = []
http_status_code_whitelist = ["200", "400", "404", "500"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately moderators closed the question, but you are a hero sir.